# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_locator'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have implemented POM model for my selenium project, I am using following logic:

I am using `get_name` method, to get locator name for my logging.

```
def get_name(locator_name: str) -> str: 
    list_of_locators = ['_XPATH', '_ID', '_CLASS_NAME', '_NAME', '_TAG_NAME']
    for word in list_of_locators:
        locator_name = locator_name.replace(word, "")
    return locator_name.replace("_", " ").title()
```

Then, I have a function to get a locator, which is like that:

```
def get_locator(self, locator: str):
    element = None
    if str(locator).endswith("_XPATH"):
        element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, locator)
    elif str(locator).endswith("_ACCESSIBILITY_ID"):
        element = self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,
                                           locator)
    elif str(locator).endswith("_ID"):
        element = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, locator)
    elif str(locator).endswith("_CLASS_NAME"):
        element = self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, locator)
    elif str(locator).endswith("_NAME"):
        element = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, locator)
    return element
```

Now this is my method:

```
def send_text(self, locator: str, value: str):
    locator_name = get_name(locator)
    self.driver.get_locator(locator).send_keys(value)
    log.logger.info("Typing in " + str(locator_name) + " and entered the value as : " + str(value))
```

and I am getting following error:

```
        locator_name = get_name(locator)
>       self.driver.get_locator(locator).send_keys(value)
E       AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_locator'
```

Where I am making a mistake. Let me know...

Comment: Try changing this line `self.driver.get_locator(locator).send_keys(value)` to `self.get_locator(locator).send_keys(value)`

Comment: Nope, still same error.

Answer (score 0):

**update your Selenium library and try this**

```
pip install --upgrade selenium

locator_name = get_name(locator)


self.driver.find_element(locator_name).send_keys(value)
```